# Fill stringstream with single character

Tags: c++, formatting, stringstream

How do I create a stringstream with a fixed length, filled with a single character?

Desired output:

```
[xxxxxxxxxx]
```

I've tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << setfill('x') << setw(10);
  cout << "[" << ss.str() << "]\n";

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[]
```

If I add anything to the stream after I set the width and fill, I get filled stream, which is what I am looking for:

```
  ss << setfill('x') << setw(10) << "B";
```

output:

```
[xxxxxxxxxB]
```

But I want a stream the stream to be filled with just *x* Is there any way to get the filled stream without needing to add a value to it?

Answer (score 1):

[setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [setfill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) are only used to set width and fill parameters of your stream, so it is normal that

```
  ss << setfill('x') << setw(10);
```

doesn't work (you don't output anything).

You may want to do something like

```
  ss << setfill('x') << setw(10) << 'x';
```

which gives

```
[xxxxxxxxxx]
```

as you wanted.

Comment: I considered this, but it seemed a little hacky. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the appropriate string [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to fill the stream, like this

```
ss << std::string(10, 'x');
```

Comment: Yeah this would accomplish what I need. Thanks for the good workaround.